# Pytest - python testing with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio

Is it possible to return execution to `event loop` from a function. And as soon `Task` will be completed return to the function and continue execution?

Im trying to use `pytest-asyncio` plugin

Example:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_async1(event_loop):
    print('start 1')
    res = event_loop.create_task(
        send_async_request("http://test.com", limit=1000))) # here I need to return execution to event loop and continue only after getting response from send_async_request function 
    print('end1',res)



@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_async2(event_loop):
    print('start 2')
    res = event_loop.create_task(
        send_async_request("http://test2", limit=1000))) # here I need to return execution to event loop and continue only after getting response from send_async_request function
    print('end2', res)
```

`send_async_request`- `aiohttp`:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def send_async_request(url, method='GET'):
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        resp = yield from session.get(url, timeout=60)
        if resp.status == 200:
            return resp.status, response
        else:
            return resp.status, False
```

Answer (score 7):

When your tests are marked with `pytest.mark.asyncio`, they become coroutines so you can use the `await` syntax:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_sleep(event_loop):
    result = await asyncio.sleep(1, result=3, loop=event_loop)
    assert result == 3
```

---

EDIT: Another example, with multiple `sleep` operations:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_multiple_sleep(event_loop):
    tasks = [event_loop.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1, result=x))
             for x in range(10)]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    assert results == list(range(10))
```

Comment: but when i'm using `await`  my code became sync. I'm wanted to send request to both urls async and continue testing. 
If I will add  `await` then there will be no difference between sync and async code . If I understand it right

Comment: For example if you add new function `test_sleep2` and add sleep time = 6 , 
then total sleep time will be 7 seconds , instead `6` which I expected. I'm expecting it in case of http request - because in `aiohttp` - http request are non-blocking

Comment: @Arseniy I added an example running multiple tasks within a test coroutine.

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple tests this way? The better what I found so far -is to add `gather` to `pytest-asyncio` itself

Comment: @Arseniy Sure, every test runs with a different `event_loop`.

Comment: @Arseniy If you want to parallelize your tests, you can also consider [pytest-xdist](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist).